# Is conversion of neon register of 1 form into another possible

Tags: arm, cpu-registers, neon

I am working on SIMD architecture by using arm neon code.
Now the problem is that in one pass of my function, I am using all the registers available in neon , so I am getting following error while compiling.

```
nw2.c: In function 'bit_24':
nw2.c:123: error: unable to find a register to spill in class 'GENERAL_REGS'
nw2.c:123: error: this is the insn:
(insn 33 32 34 5 c:\cs\codesourcery\sourcery_g++_lite\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-ea
bi/4.3.3/include/arm_neon.h:9246 (parallel [
            (set (reg:CI 178 [ D.19511 ])
                (unspec:CI [
                       (mem:CI (reg/f:SI 177 [ __a.165 ]) [0 S48 A64])
                        (reg:CI 178 [ D.19511 ])
                        (unspec:V16QI [
                                (const_int 0 [0x0])
                            ] 191)
                    ] 106))
            (set (reg/f:SI 177 [ __a.165 ])
                (plus:SI (reg/f:SI 177 [ __a.165 ])
                    (const_int 24 [0x18])))
       ]) 1593 {neon_vld3qav16qi} (nil))
 nw2.c:123: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

Now since I want to minimize the registers, I was wondering whether it is possible to use a register as 16x8 if it was initially declared as 8x16.

Please help me out

Comment: Are you using intrinsics or just raw asm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use the registers the way you want.

If you write assembler, simply apply load/process/store operations with the new types.

If you write intrinsics, that's the same... actually. Just reuse, but make sure that a moment it time, it is used in only one way.

You can also convert the way you 'see' a register. A classical trick is to load 4 chars in a reg - there is no VLD instruction for 4 chars - but you can load an int into a lane of a 4-int reg (4 bytes) in the NEON register, then cast it.

Casting only make sense with intrinsics, but in ASM, you just apply the operation you know it makes sense on the data loaded there.